# Setting permission on Drive file using Android APIs (com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi)

Tags: android, api, google-drive-api

I am creating an App using Drive Android APIs (com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi) to upload/download/share files on Google Drive. Here's the URL to sample code I am following: https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/tree/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo

The API client (com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient) prompts the user to choose an account when connecting to Google services, so I don't have user's credentials.

I am able to upload/download files using Android APIs (com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi), but there's no API to set the file permission, so that user can share it with public. The sample code too doesn't have any example to set file permission.

I googled, but found mostly examples that uses JAVA APIs which will require OAuth or API Key setup.

If anyone knows how to resolve this using Android APIs, please help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not currently available in the Android-specific API.  You can instead use the REST API for this portion of your app, authorized as described in the [Java API Client](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth#connecting_and_authorizing_with_the_google_apis_java_client).

If you have a DriveId for the file, you can get the resourceId from it which you can use to make the requests in the Java REST API.

Comment: Thanks for response. As I mentioned in my question, I did came across the examples of JAVA APIs, but it creates a different Drive (service) instance altogether, which cannot utilize power of Google Play Service on Android.

Comment: Cheryl, If using the GDAA and the Java API client within an Android app will the user have to authenticate twice (once for each?) Or is there a way to use a single Drive authentication between the play services and the REST API?

Comment: Authorization is on a per app-id basis, so if you use the same developer console project for Android and REST API, you will only need to authorize once.

Comment: Google sucks, once again. I wanted to set permissions because somehow, I got errors when I tried the download the files I had already uploaded to gDrive. Logout -> ReLogin fixed the bug!